# Strimzi / Kafka Connect does not find my plugin

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I'm using `Strimzi`, `Kafka`, `Kafka Connect` and a custom connector plugin, following [this docs](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/deploying.html#creating-new-image-from-base-str).

The deploy works fine, `Kafka Connect` is working, I can consume its `RESTFUL API`.

But the connector is not created. This is the error message:

> Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name
> matches org.company.MySourceConnector

I know the cause: it doesn't find the plugin (a jar file). But if I enter in the kafka-connect pod, I can see the jar file in the right (i suppose) place: `/opt/kafka/plugins/my-source-connector/my-source-connector.jar`.

Furthermore, I run `cat /tmp/strimzi-connect.properties` and I see the plugin path: `plugin.path=/opt/kafka/plugins/`. (the file is created by strimzi during deploy)

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnect
metadata:
  name: kafka-connect
  annotations:
    strimzi.io/use-connector-resources: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  bootstrapServers: kafka-kafka-bootstrap:9092
  image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
  config:
    group.id: connect-cluster
    ...
```

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: my-connector
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: kafka-connect
spec:
  class: org.company.MySourceConnector
  tasksMax: 1
  config:
    topic: my-topic
    name: my-connector
```

How do I configure `Strimzi` or `Kafka Connect` to find my plugin?

I exhausted all my resources. If someone could give some light on this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You can check in the status of the KafkaConnect resource what plugins were found. You can doublecheck if the name etc. is correct. You also need to make sure that all dependencies of your connector are in the same directory as well. You should also check that the paths are correct. You say that your plugin is in `/opt/kafka/plugins` but say the plugin path is `/opt/kafka/plugin` (i.e. without the `s` at the end).

Comment: I mistyped the path. I edited the post. I double checked those things again, it seems ok as far as I understand. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't see how Strimzi is related to the problem. Run the container independently, and it should run Connect process where you can verify if you the connector can be created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the jar file is corrupted.